# Parts of storyboard UI take over a minute to load

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

After I verify a user within my `LoginViewController`, I make an authorization with HealthKit, and then try to present `SummaryViewController`:

```
if ((user) != nil) {

    let healthKitAuthViewController = HealthKitAuthViewController()
    healthKitAuthViewController.healthKitAuth({(result) -> Void in
        if(result == true) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: nil)
        }
    })
}
```

I use a completion handler for the `healthKitAuth()` method inside the `HealthKitAuthViewController` class.  Within that completion handler I load `SummaryViewController`.

```
class HealthKitAuthViewController: UIViewController {

    func healthKitAuth(completion: (result: Bool) -> Void) {
        HealthData().authorizeHealthKit { (authorized,  error) -> Void in
            completion(result:true)
        }
    }
```

For some reason, in my `SummaryViewController` view there are pieces (such as a static logo and UILabel) that take up to a minute to load and I have no idea why.

Comment: Is the logo image loaded from internet?

Comment: No, its within the project.  There's also a static label that takes the same amount of time to load.

Comment: There might be some synchronous function that blocks them from being loaded. Try using a breakpoint to see if any function call you are doing is running synchronously blocking the UI loading. Place the breakpoint right above where you set the Image and text(if you are setting them programmatically) and see how long it takes for those break points for being hit

Comment: 2 out of 3 items are created on the storyboard itself.  Only one is generated programmatically, and I haven't been able to figure anything out from that part.

Comment: Try using breakpoint right from the `viewDidLoad` to check for any blocking function calls.

Comment: I have but it hasn't helped really. I'm not sure how a static image or label that is a part of the storyboard doesn't load.  The view loads fine, it's just certain pieces (seemingly random ones) don't load for a long time.

Comment: Are you absolutely, positively 100% sure that those callbacks are being called on the main thread/queue?

Comment: Yup, it's really confusing